# what exactly does modeling transformation mean?

Tags: opengl, graphics, transformation

I really couldn't get the idea. Ok, it converts from model coordinates to world coordinates but what does it consist of? rotation or translation or scaling? How can i get modeling transformation matrix?

Comment: This is about model-view transformation matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ok, it converts from model coordinates to world coordinates but what does it consist of?

The modelview transform is a mapping W(v): R^4 → R^4. The exact mapping can be freely defined using a vertex shader. In the usual case it follow the fixed function pipeline, which uses a linear mapping v' ⟼ M v, where M is a 4×4 matrix.

> rotation or translation or scaling?

It's a mapping R^4 → R^4. Any mapping that falls into this group can be used as a modelview transform. Rotations, scalings and translations and any combination of them fall into the group, but there are many more.

> How can i get modeling transformation matrix?

From OpenGL? Preferrably not, because OpenGL is not a math library. In fact, that whole matrix stack has been stripped away from later versions of OpenGL. You build those matrices yourself (hence you already have them) and then load them into a OpenGL uniform state variable.